# Flash Pro CS6 - adMob not working after Google play services update

Tags: flash, admob, ane

I have spent quite a few days trying to solve this but it is not working.

I was using adMobManager from: https://github.com/lancelot1/ane-admob

This was working before the new google play services update.

My code:

```
import com.codealchemy.ane.admobane.AdMobManager;
import com.codealchemy.ane.admobane.*;
var adMobManager:AdMobManager;
adMobManager = AdMobManager.manager;

if(adMobManager.isSupported){

    adMobManager.verbose = true;
    adMobManager.operationMode = AdMobManager.TEST_MODE;
    adMobManager.bannersAdMobId = "My AD ID";


    adMobManager.createBanner(AdMobSize.BANNER, AdMobPosition.TOP_CENTER, "TopBanner1", "My Ad id", true);



    adMobManager.showBanner("TopBanner1");


};
```

XML:

```
     <android>
    <manifestAdditions>
      <![CDATA[
      <manifest android:installLocation="auto">
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
                <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
                    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="4452000" />
                    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
                </application>              
    </manifest>]]>
    </manifestAdditions>
  </android>
  <extensions>
    <extensionID>com.codealchemy.ane.admobane</extensionID>
  </extensions>
```

The above was supposed to work (as it did before the updates) but it doesn't.

What can I do?

I need to implement Ads ASAP!!!

Thank you.

EDIT: I am using AIR 14 SDK for Android.

Comment: You are going to need to be more specific than 'not working'

Comment: Do you get any message in logcat?

Comment: I mean it is not working anymore when it used to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

S4VV4S,
First at all your code is not incorrect. There are some few thing which you can improve, but those thing will not resolve the problem, only improve the code.

For example:

Change:

```
import com.codealchemy.ane.admobane.AdMobManager;
import com.codealchemy.ane.admobane.*;
```

to

```
import com.codealchemy.ane.admobane.*;
```

Even better would be to import exclusively the class you use rather then all.

then,
if you are using:

```
adMobManager.bannersAdMobId = "My AD ID";
```

Then you don't need to specify a specific admobId during banner creation therefore you can change:

```
adMobManager.createBanner(AdMobSize.BANNER, AdMobPosition.TOP_CENTER, "TopBanner1", "My Ad id", true);
```

to:

```
adMobManager.createBanner(AdMobSize.BANNER, AdMobPosition.TOP_CENTER, "TopBanner1", null, true);
```

Unless, you want to use a specific AdmobId for the specific banner (this is convenient when you want to track specific banner usage stats).

But in Most of the Application you just use one ID for all the banners, so, since you did already specify the default AdMob ID in:

```
adMobManager.bannersAdMobId = "My AD ID";
```

It would be better to avoid write the Id again which may be source of mistypes errors.

Finally, if you use the autoshow (option true) during banner creation then you don't need to use:

```
adMobManager.showBanner("TopBanner1");
```

Since the banner it will be show automatically.

Therefore remove it.
If you want to show it manually you need to use the showBanner call inside an event Listener and show the banner only when the banner is actually loaded.
Called as that it will only generate a miss shot, which may cause problems.
Miss shoots are already handle internally by the ANE, however it is better to avoid chances. Better safe than sorry.

**Now, for the Main problem itself.**
As a matter of fact, we are currently using the latest update ANE with the Latest GPS on our app as well, and we are not facing the problem, the request are loaded at 99.8%.
This goes also for several other professionals which are including the ANE on their APP/Games.

However We did too occasionally experience some problem on missed request loading (which are pretty annoying) but this is happening very rarely and only with interstitial.

As correctly pointed out from William and tsukimi, the logcat will be extremely helpful for better understand what generates the issue.

Sharing my experience on similar issues i can give you these advises:

**Check 1:** Even if you are using:

```
adMobManager.operationMode = AdMobManager.TEST_MODE;
```

You must provide valid AdmobID created in AdMob website. If a not valid ID is use or it has a misspell then the request will fail ergo the banner will not show.
Please make certain of the correct AdMob ID

**Check 2:** Remember that AdMob ID for Banner and Interstitial are not the same. For Banner use exclusively AmobId created for banners, while for interstitial create exclusively AdmobId created for interstitial.

**Check 3:** Add an event listener to the application and log when they are called.
Example:
Create Dispatcher Instance

```
/**
 * Extension event dispatcher instance
 **/
private function get dispatcher():EventDispatcher
{
    // Return the extension dispatcher
    return adMobManager.dispatcher;
}
```

Set Events Listeners

```
// onBannerLoaded Event Listener
if (!dispatcher.hasEventListener(AdMobEvent.BANNER_LOADED))
    dispatcher.addEventListener(AdMobEvent.BANNER_LOADED, onBannerLoaded);
```

Handle the Event

```
/**
 * onBannerLoaded Event listener
 *
 * @param e AdMobEvent Object
 **/
private function onBannerLoaded(e:AdMobEvent):void
{
    // Show the specific banner which did dispatch the event
    // e.data:String = Banner unique ID
    adMobManager.showBanner(e.data);
}
```

**Check 4:** Be certain that the device has actual connection to the network, if there is no connection the request cannot be performed and/or completed ergo the banner will not show up.
I will advise to create a connection monitor class for manage and handle the loss of connection.

**Check 5:** Consider that the Banner debug can only be performed on actual devices. you cant see or debug the banner work flow from desktop or any simulator.

This is all come in my mind as check/advise list, if all these check are done you should not encounter the problem.

One last word, we have never experienced any errors with the banners in Admob, however Google is actively deprecating the old SDK right now, some downside during the deprecation/Update may be notice also on the GPS service until their operation completes.

I Hope the answer is helpful.

Comment: Hi, when I said "My ID" I am actually using my adMob ID I just didn't post it :)

Comment: Also I am using Flash Pro not Flash Builder.

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing a similar problem in FlashDevelop, but probably because I just recently started using Code-Alchemy's ANE, I never saw it working properly. I tried using other ANE's, and incidentally, those using the soon-to-be-depreacted stand-alone AdMob SDK actually do work (BrinkBit's and some other feature-limited free AdMob ANE). Code-Alchemy's and lilili87222's (https://github.com/lilili87222/admob-for-flash) ANE's use the new Google Play Service and up until now, I wasn't able to receive any ad. The event listeners do not get called.

So, this won't be a proper answer, but for the short term, you could use one of the ANE's that use the standalone SDK. BrinkBit's ANE is commercial and featured-rich, but you can try out the demo version. Don't forget to remove the <meta-data> under <application> if you do. Standalone clients throw an error otherwise. Also, only one <extensionID> tag for AdMob is allowed, so comment-out the one for code-alchemy if you place some other ID.

Meanwhile, let's hope Code-Alchemy and/or Google fix whatever's wrong with the service.

Comment: Seems like I actually had a much different problem. After replacing "com.google.ads.AdActivity" with "com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" in the manifest section, ads started being displayed.